# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null on event.target

Tags: javascript, events, dispatch

I have `event.target` nested on a custom function.

```js
_buttonPublish = (event) => {
  var TreeMap = this.state.TreeMap;
  this.state.ObjectTree.forEach(item => {
    TreeMap.push(this._parseItemToTreeMap(item));
    this.setState({
      TreeMap: TreeMap,
      publish: true
    }, () => {
      event.target.style.top = item.position.y;
      event.target.style.left = item.position.x;
    });
  });
}

<button type="button" onClick={(e) => this._buttonPublish(e)} style={{width: 200, height: 100}}>
      Publish!
    </button>
```

Why style is undefined?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean "dispatch and event to `event.target.value` to change properties from it". What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: `setState`'s callback doesn't receive an `event` argument as far as I'm aware. Is this defined? Where is it coming from?

Comment: It's undefined. How do i define it?

Comment: It’s unclear what you want to do though. Change the position of the button that calls the `_buttonPublish` method? If so, how? The relationship between `event` and `item` is unclear.

Comment: Also, regarding `TreeMap`, don’t try to mutate state with `push`/`unshift` etc, you’ll want to move that into your `setState`

Comment: How are you calling `_buttonPublish`? What value does `event` actually have?

Comment: Im calling _buttonPublish by clicking a button. event has null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make use of React's synthetic event within `setState`'s asynchronous context, I had to call `event.persist()` on it. This allows you to access `event` in the `setState` callback:

```js
// this function just simulates the properties you seem to have on `ObjectTree`'s elements
function makeTreeItem() {
  function randint(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.abs(max - min) + min);
  }
  return {
    position: {
      x: `${randint(0, 100)}px`,
      y: `${randint(0, 100)}px`
    }
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      ObjectTree: [
        makeTreeItem(),
        makeTreeItem(),
        makeTreeItem(),
        makeTreeItem()
      ]
    };
  }
  handleClick = event => {
    event.persist();
    this.state.ObjectTree.forEach(item => {
      this.setState(
        {
          publish: true
        },
        () => {
          // access and adjust the event `target`'s position
          event.target.style.top = item.position.y;
          event.target.style.left = item.position.x;
        }
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          Publish!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It definitely feels like something is still missing here regarding your desired outcome, ie you set the position of the button based on the positional properties of the last element in your `state.ObjectTree` array: that is a very confusing UI pattern in my opinion, but at least you should now be able to access `event`.